# Android notifications on defined time and date

Tags: android, notifications

I want my application to remind user to watch a tv-show weekly... Is it possible to make notification to popup every week in desired time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Setup your calender for a reminder on the day/time in questions, and then just set it up to remind weekly. its an option on there. it might be easier for you to set it up from the web version of google calender, but it is just as easy on your phone.

Comment: Thanks for answer but you didnt understand my question. Im wondering can I program my app to do that:)